# Use numbers as column names while grouping them

Tags: r

Here is my sample data;

```
mydata<-structure(list(x1 = c(0, 8.6, 11.2, 8.4, 0, 0), x2 = c(0, 0, 
7.8, 7.6, 1.2, 10.2), y1 = c(0, 0, 3.4, 21.4, 1.8, 1.4), y2 = c(7.8, 
7.6, 1.2, 10.2, 7, 0), z1 = c(0, 1.6, 7.6, 23.6, 3.2, 0), z2 = c(8.6, 
1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2", "z1", "z2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


    x1   x2   y1   y2   z1  z2
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  7.8  0.0 8.6
2  8.6  0.0  0.0  7.6  1.6 1.4
3 11.2  7.8  3.4  1.2  7.6 0.0
4  8.4  7.6 21.4 10.2 23.6 0.0
5  0.0  1.2  1.8  7.0  3.2 0.0
6  0.0 10.2  1.4  0.0  0.0 0.0
```

With the code below, it is possible to group columns as `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
grps <- unique(gsub("[0-9]", "", colnames(mydata)))
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

But When I rename columns like that;

```
myd<-structure(list(X2005 = c(0, 8.6, 11.2, 8.4, 0, 0), X2005.1 = c(0, 
0, 7.8, 7.6, 1.2, 10.2), X2006 = c(0, 0, 3.4, 21.4, 1.8, 1.4), 
    X2006.1 = c(7.8, 7.6, 1.2, 10.2, 7, 0), X2007 = c(0, 1.6, 
    7.6, 23.6, 3.2, 0), X2007.1 = c(8.6, 1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("X2005", 
"X2005.1", "X2006", "X2006.1", "X2007", "X2007.1"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")


  X2005 X2005.1 X2006 X2006.1 X2007 X2007.1
1   0.0     0.0   0.0     7.8   0.0     8.6
2   8.6     0.0   0.0     7.6   1.6     1.4
3  11.2     7.8   3.4     1.2   7.6     0.0
4   8.4     7.6  21.4    10.2  23.6     0.0
5   0.0     1.2   1.8     7.0   3.2     0.0
6   0.0    10.2   1.4     0.0   0.0     0.0
```

I want to see;

```
# [1] "2005" "2006" "2007"
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected output  If it more than one digit, then use `[0-9]+`

Comment: I mean, I can group the columns by x, y, z letters. But how can I group them by using numbers as column names instead of letters (x,y,z)?

Comment: If you can show the expected output, it is not clear to me what you expect.  What is the use of that group?  Is it to split into different dataset?  Is this to use with a different package?

Comment: If you want to use a column name which is a number , then `group_by(\`2005\`, \`2006\`, \`2007\`)` should still work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match the letter 'X' at the beginning (`^`) of the string or (`|` the `.` followed by numbers at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
names(myd) <- gsub("^X|\\.\\d+$", "", names(myd))
names(myd)
#[1] "2005" "2005" "2006" "2006" "2007" "2007"

unique(names(myd))
#[1] "2005" "2006" "2007"
```

---

If we know the number of digits and position, then `substr` would be faster

```
substr(names(myd), 2, 5)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add extensions like x1,x2,y1,y2 etc. as in my question?  For example: `2005.1`, `2006.1` and `2007.1`. Because functions in my script are looking the number of extension. For example there are codes like `mean(mydata[,paste0(x, 1)]` and `mean(mydata[,paste0(x, 2)]`. With the first code; I am obtaining mean of first column of 2005 and with the second code, finding mean of second column of 2005

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi  Yes, you can do `make.unique(names(myd)))`

Comment: Or another option is `paste(names(myd), ave(seq_along(names(myd)), names(myd), FUN = seq_along), sep=".")`

Comment: Sorry for asking too much. The second code is useful for me. But how can I obtain `#[1] "2005" "2006" "2007"`  after applying second code in your comments?

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi  Just remove the numbers with `unique(sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(myd)))`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to to use `sub` and convert the names to `factor` with `labels` as needed.

```
names(mydata) <- factor(sub("[0-9]", "", names(mydata)), labels = 2005:2007)
```

and then check your column names

```
names(mydata)
#[1] "2005" "2005" "2006" "2006" "2007" "2007"
```